# Optimizing loading complex tree from DB with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, npgsql

Initial query structure:

```
        var a = await _Db.A
            .Include(a => a.B)
                .ThenInclude(b => b.C1)
                    .ThenInclude(c1 => c1.D)
            .Include(a => a.B)
                .ThenInclude(b => b.C2)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
```

The problem is that because B has two sub trees the result of the generated query has a row for each combination of the values from these subtrees. Two separate queries would give two results that are in total much smaller. So I tried, to load the second tree separately with
an explicit load.

```
        var a = await _Db.A
            .Include(a => a.B)
                .ThenInclude(b => b.C1)
                    .ThenInclude(c1 => c1.D)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);

        _Db.Entry(a).Collection(a => a.B).Query()
            .Include(b => b.C2);
```

How ever the explicit load does nothing, I guess because B is already filled and it never checks if `C2` needs filling. So is there anyway to get this to work?

The database provider is Npgsql. An Npgsql specific solution would be acceptable but a native EF core solution would be preferred.

Comment: Neither of your examples is complete. They only build `IQueryable` objects, not load them. FYI `.AsSplitQuery()` will generate a query per table to avoid generating any cartesian product joins.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, updated sample code, I'll test AsSplitQuery

Comment: `AsSplitQuery` gives me in the real code 4 queries which is not optimal but it is 20 times faster then `AsSingleQuery` which is good enough.

Comment: Did you forget `.Load()` on the last query?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, yes I did thx, tested it does indeed load C2 now logs two queries as I wanted. Performance is close AsSplitQuery.